# Can I set HelveticaNeueInterface-M3?

Tags: ios7, uilabel, uifont

Just a simple question: Can I set the system iOS7 font (HelveticaNeueInterface-M3) by code to use it in a label like: [label setFont:[UIFont fontwithName:@"..." size:14]]; Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use

> [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]
>
> for Light: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14]];
>
> for Thin: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:14]];
>
> for Bold: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14]];

in iOS7 it should also work

> [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:14]